# update package in debian

Tags: linux, debian

i have tshark installed in my debian linux which has version of 1.2.11. I want to update it to 1.8.0-1. I am trying it updated using

```
apt-get update
```

But, it still the latest version is not installed. Is this the way to update a package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apt-get update` (as sudo)

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Hope this help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Calling

```
apt-get update
```

only updates the list with available packages.

You need to run

```
apt-get upgrade
```

after "apt-get update" to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system.

See the man page for apt-get (you can also view it online e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)